# The physical representation of graph is represented as follows

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

[image: graph representation img]

Traversal: DFS

what vertices are not pushed in?

I don't understand the solution below in img why 5,7 not pushed into the stack.
After backtracking from 7 to 8. we can visit to 5 and push. But solution provided I'm unable to understand.

[image: solution img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You push a node only if you're going to visit its children. And the stack trace shows that you never visit a node that's already been visited. If you were to re-visit a node, you invite infinite recursion.

5 isn't pushed onto the stack because when you visit node 5, you see that its two children, 8 and 2, have already been visited. So you go to the next child of node 8, which is 6. It, too has been visited already, so you skip it and go to 7. Both of its children also have been visited, so you don't visit them again from 7.